# What is missing from my build environment when trying to compile emacs-25.1?

Tags: emacs, build

I'm trying to build emacs-25.1 from source on OSx. Everything goes fine until `make install`. When Emacs is trying to compile `xml.c` I get:

```
xml.c:23:10: fatal error: 'libxml/tree.h' file not found
#include <libxml/tree.h>
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague was having the same problem and posted in the GNU emacs devel list right [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-11/msg01940.html). Daniel Suton provided the answer. Xcode is missing:

```
xcode-select --install
```

MacOS provides a libxml implementation (and headers) by default when you install xcode. Note that I had installed xcode already. But I've also upgraded from EL Captain to Sierra so my xcode installation must have been erased in the process.

Anyway, after installing xcode like described above and then after `git clean -fxd` I was able to rebuild emacs again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your exact error is. However, there is an easier way to build emacs25 on OSX and macOS. Install homebrew is easy and once you have it, all you need to do is run

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-rsvg --with-ns
```

and then

```
brew linkapps emacs
```

and your done. Even if you want to do it by hand, you can get the recipe homebrew users to see how it does the build and install, which might help track down your error.

*NOTE* Check what the actual args are you can pass to the build environment. the ones I've listed are from memory and there are some others you may want to include.